# TypeError: this.source is not a function, this.source is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm trying to redo [this tutorial](http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Search/index.html), when I search autocomplete I have error **TypeError: this.source is not a function. (In 'this.source( { term: value }, this._response() )', 'this.source' is null)**

```
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            stateLayer.addData(data);
                        console.log(data);
            for (i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {  //loads State Name into an Array for searching
                arr1.push({label:data.features[i].properties.STATE_NAME, value:""});
            }
           addDataToAutocomplete(arr1);  //passes array for sorting and to load search control.
        });
     stateLayer.addTo(map);
    function addDataToAutocomplete(arr) {
                     
            arr.sort(function(a, b){ // sort object by Name
                var nameA=a.label, nameB=b.label
                if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
                    return -1 
                if (nameA > nameB)
                    return 1
                return 0 //default return value (no sorting)
            })
    
            // The source for autocomplete.  https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-option
            $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete("option", "source", arr); 
        
            $( "#autocomplete" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {
                polySelect(ui.item.label);  //grabs selected state name
                ui.item.value='';
            });
        }
```

Comment: In your `$.getJSON` function `arr1` is not defined. Where do you declare your `arr1` array?

Comment: @firatozcevahir arr1 already declared outside function

Comment: Within addDataToAutocomplete(arr), check if arr is array, or log to console for the contents.